# Angular-meteor client-side test can not load myApp module

Tags: meteor, angular-meteor

I would like to test my meteor-angular app. I installed the packages `angular:angular-mocks` and `angular:angular-mocks`.
Then I created a file: `Client/test/first.test.js`
I have inserted the following code:

```
import chai from 'meteor/practicalmeteor:chai';

        describe('MessageCtrl', function () {

            beforeEach(angular.module('myApp'));  

            it('does something that should be tested', function () {
                var expect = chai.expect;
                expect("foo").to.be.a('string');
            })
        });
```

The tests I have started with `meteor test -setting settings.json --driver-package practicalmeteor:mocha`, but I always get the error:

```
angular_angular.js?hash=ba46867…:93Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] 
Module 'myApp' is not available! 
You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. 
If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies 
as the second argument
```

What am I doing wrong? I thought Meteor automatically integrated all the files.

Thanks

Update

Make a import with `import '../lib/app.ng.js'`  do nothing change.

Comment: Did you try to import your module `myApp` ?

Comment: yes, but nothing changed :-(